# Concatenate multiple cells in a selection into a single string cell with newline/carriage returns

Tags: excel, vba

I need to concatenate multiple cells in a selection of multiple rows into a single string cell with newline/carriage returns

e.g. Selection image:

[image]

After concatenation it should look like this:

[image]

My code does the concatenating into one cell but not adding the newline:

```
Sub concat_3()
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim txt As String

    For Each row In Selection
        For Each cell In row.Cells
            txt = txt & cell.Value
        Next cell
        txt = txt & vbCrLf
    Next row
    Selection.ClearContents
    txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 2)
    Selection(1).Value = txt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code with For loops (not For Each) and it kinda works for me. Try.

```
Sub concat_3()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim txt As String

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set c = Selection
    txt = ""
    For i = 1 To c.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To c.Columns.Count
            txt = txt & c(i, j).Value
        Next j
        txt = txt & vbCrLf
    Next i

    txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 2)
    'to output in Sheet1 A1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = txt
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey nightcrawler, how can I write the out put to a different worksheet in the same workbook so I can preserve the original data? I tried the worksheet.Activate....

Answer (score 0):

Here is another go:

Before:

[image]

Some code:

```
Sub fhuscvc()
    Dim s As String, i As Long, a As Range
    i = 0
    s = ""

    For Each a In Selection
        s = s & "    " & a.Value
        i = i + 1
        If i = 2 Then
            i = 0
            s = s & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next a

    Selection.Clear
    Selection(1).Value = s
End Sub
```

And after:

[image]

The fixed block of spaces separating each pair of items is not pretty....too bad the *TAB* character does not work inside cells.

Comment: This will work for 2 column selections, not any number of columns. :)